In MS-Word dynamically recode selected hyperlink
The below code struggles with existing hyperlinked text.
Any insights would be greatly appreciated.
The selected text to be linked is: A1234567
If the text part "A123456" is hyperlinked, selection/range is "A1234567", it only re-hyperlinks "A123456".
Other things the script must deal with is ignore non numeric's at the end i.e.:
A1234567/ A1234568, A1234569;
Not removing newlines (moving lines up):
A1234567
A1234568
Text as per above within table columns.
Oh and at one stage I'd select the text, it would insert the hyperlink and also retain the existing text.  I'd Ctrl-Z, do it again, and it would work fine (weirdness!).
Think I've looked at the code too much... this should be simple!!!
Dim rng As Range
Dim id As String
Dim regex As Object
Dim matches As Object
Dim hyperlinkUrl As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim foundHyperlink As Boolean
Dim existingHyperlink As Hyperlink

' Define the regular expression to match IDs starting with A followed by 7 digits
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
regex.IgnoreCase = True
regex.Global = True
regex.Pattern = "\bA\d{7}\b" ' Matches A followed by exactly 7 digits

' Get the selection
Set rng = Selection.Range

' Check if the selected text is already a hyperlink
foundHyperlink = False
For Each existingHyperlink In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
    If existingHyperlink.Range = rng Then
        foundHyperlink = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next existingHyperlink

' Apply the regex pattern to find all matching IDs in the selected text
Set matches = regex.Execute(rng.Text)

' Loop through each match and create or update a hyperlink
For i = 0 To matches.Count - 1
    id = matches.Item(i).Value
    ' Create the URL with the matched ID
    hyperlinkUrl = "www.website.com/id:" & id & "@port:8643"
   
    If foundHyperlink Then
        ' If the text is already a hyperlink, update the URL and text
        existingHyperlink.Address = hyperlinkUrl
        existingHyperlink.TextToDisplay = id
    Else
        ' If no hyperlink found, create a new hyperlink
        Set rng = Selection.Range
        rng.Find.Execute FindText:=id
       
        If rng.Find.Found Then
            ' Create a new hyperlink at the found location
            ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add _
                Anchor:=rng, _
                Address:=hyperlinkUrl, _
                TextToDisplay:=id
        End If
    End If
Next i


You can use wildcards with Word's Find method, but seemingly that fails if only part of the Id is hyperlinked.  One workaround is to first remove any existing link(s) which match a given pattern.  Or just remove all links if there are no other types of links expected in the selection.
Sub LinkUpdate()
    Dim rng As Range, ids As Collection, idRng As Range, url As String, txt As String
    
    Set rng = Selection.Range 'Get the selection
    
    RemoveHyperlinks rng, "*google.com*" 'remove any matched existing links
    
    Set ids = AllIds(rng)
    Debug.Print ids.Count
    
    For Each idRng In ids
        txt = idRng.Text
        url = "http://google.com?q=" & txt
        
        idRng.Document.Hyperlinks.Add _
            Anchor:=idRng, Address:=url, TextToDisplay:=txt
    Next
End Sub

'Find all instances of A####### in range `rng` and return
'   as a collection
Function AllIds(rng As Range) As Collection 'of Ranges
    Set AllIds = New Collection
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Text = "<A[0-9]{7}>"
        Do While .Execute
            Debug.Print "Found", rng.Text, rng.Start, rng.End
            AllIds.Add rng.Duplicate
        Loop
    End With
End Function

'Remove any existing hyperlinks from Range `rng`
'  if the link address matches the pattern `patt`
Sub RemoveHyperlinks(rng As Range, patt As String)
    Dim lnk As Hyperlink, i As Long
    For i = rng.Hyperlinks.Count To 1 Step -1 'looping backwards
        Set lnk = rng.Hyperlinks(i)
        If LCase(lnk.Address) Like LCase(patt) Then lnk.Delete
    Next i
End Sub


Thanks for the fast post.  I need it to account for user error, when the user has previously manually hyperlinked "A123456" its displayed in blue, the 7 at the end is black. The script seems to ignore this scenario. Also, I'd like it to do just the selected text, not the whole document.  It should be simple... but proving very hard

Hmmm seems like Find, although able to match an id which has a hyperlink on the whole 8 characters, will not match when fewer characters are linked.  Are all of the existing (pre-replace) hyperlinks of the same format (same URL pattern)?  It might be easier to first remove them all, and then add the new ones.

Updated my answer.
